# how to access self managed docker registry hosted on AWS EC2 from windows machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy, docker-registry, amazon-elb

**I want to setup a self managed docker private registry on an EC2 instance without using AWS ECR/ECS services i.e. using the docker registry:2 container image and make it accessible to the development team so that they can push/pull docker images remotely.**
The development team has windows laptop with "docker for windows" installed in it.

**Please note:**

The EC2 instance is hosted on private subnet.

I have already created a AWS-ALB with openssl self-signed certificate and attached it to the EC2 so that the server can be accessed over HTTPS Listener.

I have deployed docker registry using below command:

**docker run -d -p 8080:5000 --restart=always --name registry registry:2**

I think pre-routing of 443 to 8080 is done because when I hit the browser with
**https:///v2/_catalog** I get an output in json format.
Currently, the catalog is empty because there is no image pushed in the registry.

**I expect this docker-registry hosted on AWS-EC2 instance to be accessible remotely i.e. from windows remote machine as well.**

Any references/suggestions/steps to achieve my task would be really helpful.

Hoping for a quick resolution.

Thanks and Regards,

Rohan Shetty

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Make an EC2 instance reachable from the internet?

Comment: @lexicore I have resolved the issue by following the below steps: 
1.  added --insecure-registry parameter in the docker.service file 2.  created a new directory "certs.d/<domain-name>" at path /etc/docker .( Please note: Here domain name is the one at which docker-registry is to be accessed) 3.  Placed the self-signed openssl certificate and key for the domain-name inside the above mentioned directory...thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by following the below steps:

1. added --insecure-registry parameter in the docker.service file
2. created a new directory "certs.d/my-domain-name" at path /etc/docker.
   ( Please note: Here domain name is the one at which docker-registry is to be accessed)
3. Placed the self-signed openssl certificate and key for the domain-name inside the above mentioned directory
4. restart docker